# how to show a list of the last 10 searches in my repository

Tags: java, service, repository

this is my first post on SO... please forgive if I leave something important out and feel free to educate me on appropriate protocols.

I am new to Java and working on a practice application for searching the weather using zipcodes and the openweathermap api.

The **challenge I am having right now** is showing the last 10 searches in a list on the index.html page. Already I have a list of ALL the last searches, but I need it to only show the last 10 (cause the DB can get too big to show all).

Here is the display of all the zipCodes searched:

```
<div class="container div_mit_background justify-content-center">
    <p>List of previous searches</p>
    <div class="list-group" th:each="zip:${zipCodes}">
        <div class"list-group-item list-group-item-action">
            <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                <h5><span th:text="${zip.zipCode}"></span></h5>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my ZipRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface ZipRepository extends CrudRepository<Zip, Long>{
    List<Zip> findAll();
    List<Zip> findFirst10ByIdZipByIdDesc(Long id);
}
```

and here is call to the WeatherService.java

```
public List<Zip> findFirst10ByIdZipByIdDesc(Zip zip) {
    List<Zip> zips = zipRepository.findFirst10ByIdZipByIdDesc(zip);
    return zips;
}
```

Of course that (zip) is incorrect... and this is where I am looking for some help.

Please advise.

Comment: Can you clarify, please, about the "last" and "first," here? I hear that you are looking for the last 10 (I assume chronologically), but I see a function called `findFirst10By…`. I am also confused about looking up 10 searches by zip code… won't all 10 be the same?

Comment: Would like to get the last 10 (chronologically speaking) zip codes that were searched. I thought I saw there was some way to use Pageable and .DESC to use the findFirst10By in DESC order.

Answer (score 0):

One of my teammates found this one: `findAllByOrderByIdDesc();`
and that worked along with creating the list and passing if with `.subList(0,10);`

here is the full code for the WeatherService.java class

```
    public List<Zip> findLastTen() {
        List<Zip> zipCodesList = zipRepository.findAllByOrderByIdDesc();
        List<Zip> lastTenSearches = zipCodesList.subList(0,10);
        return lastTenSearches;
    }
```

Comment: Presumably, the `zipRepository` is responsible for making calls to the database. If it is returning all of the orders in order for you to only take 10 of them, then you haven't solved the issue of the dataset growing too large. The task of taking 10 could be done at the data query step. It is also possible that the query is deferred; I don't know the implementation. I'd also suggest that you probably want the last 10 _unique_ searches.

Comment: @Jay this is an excellent point. I did find some potential solutions similar to my first attempt at implementation. Using something like findLastTenByCreatedAt or something like this.